# JSF 2 Mojarra and exceptions when using Value Expression behaves unexpected

Tags: jsf-2, mojarra

Say a facelets has e.g 10 outputtexts bound with value expressions to 10 different fields in the bean. If exception occurs when calling the first getter, should the following 9 still be called?

Because this is the behavior I am seeing when testing this. It causes grave problems with a legacy module that has been boosted up to use JSF 2.

I am using Mojarra 2.1.16 and tried with Mojarra 2.1.6. Tried with both weld and JSF2 beans. Container is Tomcat 7.

Can this behavior be altered somehow? I can't imagine this being desired behavior.

The code I used to reproduce it below:

*EDIT: This is not the production code, this simply shows the unexpected behavior.*

**Relevant facelet code:**

```
<h:inputText value="#{testController.a}"></h:inputText>
<h:inputText value="#{testController.b}"></h:inputText>
<h:inputText value="#{testController.c}"></h:inputText>
<h:inputText value="#{testController.d}"></h:inputText>
<h:inputText value="#{testController.e}"></h:inputText>
<h:inputText value="#{testController.f}"></h:inputText>
<h:inputText value="#{testController.g}"></h:inputText>
<h:inputText value="#{testController.h}"></h:inputText>
```

**Relevant bean code**

```
private String a, b, c ,d, e, f, g, h;

    public String getA() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        System.out.println("b was called");
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getC() {
        System.out.println("c was called");
        return c;
    }

    public void setC(String c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public String getD() {
        System.out.println("d was called");
        return d;
    }

    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

    public String getE() {
        System.out.println("e was called");
        return e;
    }

    public void setE(String e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public String getF() {
        System.out.println("f was called");
        return f;
    }

    public void setF(String f) {
        this.f = f;
    }

    public String getG() {
        System.out.println("g was called");
        return g;
    }

    public void setG(String g) {
        this.g = g;
    }

    public String getH() {
        System.out.println("h was called");
        return h;
    }

    public void setH(String h) {
        this.h = h;
    }
```

**JSF 2.1.6 with a managed bean:**

```
2013-jan-09 13:54:41 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\CollabNet\Subversion Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt;C:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt1;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Groovy\Groovy-1.8.6\bin;c:\projects\maven\bin;;.
2013-jan-09 13:54:41 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
VARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:demo' did not find a matching property.
2013-jan-09 13:54:41 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
2013-jan-09 13:54:41 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
2013-jan-09 13:54:41 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 706 ms
2013-jan-09 13:54:41 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
2013-jan-09 13:54:41 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
2013-jan-09 13:54:47 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.6 (SNAPSHOT 20111206) for context '/demo'
2013-jan-09 13:54:48 com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
VARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.NotNull, but that class is not presented
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
VARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty, but that class is not presented
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
VARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.Size, but that class is not presented
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
VARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.Pattern, but that class is not presented
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
VARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.Min, but that class is not presented
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
VARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.Max, but that class is not presented
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
VARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue, but that class is not presented
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
VARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.AssertFalse, but that class is not presented
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.cache.CacheManager getCacheFactory
INFO: Selected fallback cache factory
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.cache.lru.LRUMapCacheFactory createCache
INFO: Creating LRUMap cache instance using parameters: {facelets.DEVELOPMENT=true, javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE=Development, org.richfaces.enableControlSkinning=true, javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX=.xhtml}
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.cache.lru.LRUMapCacheFactory createCache
INFO: Creating LRUMap cache instance of 512 items capacity
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener onStart
INFO: RichFaces Core Implementation by JBoss by Red Hat, version v.4.2.0.Final
2013-jan-09 13:54:51 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/demo/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
2013-jan-09 13:54:52 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
2013-jan-09 13:54:52 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
2013-jan-09 13:54:52 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10510 ms
2013-jan-09 13:55:30 com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
ALLVARLIG: Error Rendering View[/rdfieldset/rdfieldset.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /rdfieldset/rdfieldset.xhtml @13,42 value="#{testController.a}": Error reading 'a' on type com.wmdata.raindance.webcomp.links.demo.TestController
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1757)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.wmdata.raindance.webcomp.fileUpload.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:67)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception
    at com.wmdata.raindance.webcomp.links.demo.TestController.getA(TestController.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 39 more
b was called
c was called
d was called
e was called
f was called
g was called
h was called
```

**JSF 2.1.16 with CDI-bean**

```
jan 09, 2013 1:59:52 EM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/start.xhtml]
javax.el.ELException: /start.xhtml @26,49 value="#{testController.a}": Error reading 'a' on type test.testController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:114)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.render(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:126)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception
    at test.testController.getA(testController.java:44)
    at test.testController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getA(testController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    ... 39 more

b was called
c was called
d was called
e was called
f was called
g was called
h was called
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem with Mojarra 2.1.16 on Tomcat. It's perhaps JBoss EL specific. Can you please post the stacktrace when using JSF managed bean instead of CDI managed bean. Please also post stacktrace in code block not in quote block.

Comment: @BalusC Really? That's quite interesting. Well afaik we use the el tomcat provides. Thank you and I updated question accordingly to your comment.

Comment: This is weird. I get exactly the same stacktrace for Mojarra 2.1.6 on Tomcat, but the webapp fails nicely with an error page and remaining getters are not invoked. Do you happen to have some JSF/EL-specific classes overridden somewhere in your Java source (which thus ends up in `/WEB-INF/classes`)

Comment: @BalusC Not what I know of. It works as expected with myfaces 2.1.10. I will check for sure and report back

Comment: @BalusC Just checked it out and no such overridden classes. It's strange.